# multiple apps from one certificate

Tags: ios, certificate, codenameone

I have two active projects, my main app and a test app.  It seems to
be the case that using the "generate" button to run the certificate
wizard, I have to generate certificates from scratch each time I switch
from one app to the other.  The "use existing" option never works.
Generating a new cert for one app invalidates the cert for the other app.   This doesn't seem right, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is it you are calling the certificate wizard?

Comment: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/ios-certificate-wizard.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is the assumption that use existing didn't work.

When you pick use existing it will only generate provisioning and you need to copy the P12 files from the other project where they are valid. You can define a single set of P12 files for the entire IDE in the IDE global preferences. Then you just run the certificate wizard to regenerate the provisioning or do it manually in the apple website.

Comment: so the wizard isn't wizardly enough to find the existing certificates if you use existing?

Comment: The certificates on the apple server are no longer useful once the P12 is generated. We don't store your data in our servers as that would violate privacy.  Since you can move a project location or P12 file location we can't really rely on the place you stored them last.

Comment: One small wrinkle - the certificate wizard, when you generate a new certificate, fills in the "certificate password field", which can't be copied and pasted between projects.  I can copy the certificates, but what is the password?

Comment: It's in the codenameone_settings.properties file in the project.

Answer (score 1):

**If you are asking about creating new certificates...** ...associated to with your public/private key pair

You do not need to keep creating new CSR, and new keys with that.
The documentation is a bit fuzzy regarding that, and you can quickly end with a collection of keys, certificates, and the like.

**In Keychain access:**

Select *Login > Keys >* **your private key**, or **your existing certificate**

[image]

Select *Keychain Access > Certificate Assistant*

Notice that when you have a Certificate, a Key, etc. selected, the certificate assistant uses that object as the starting point.

**No starting point:**
[image: No starting point]

**With starting point:**
[image: Starting point]

Doing it this way will use the existing object instead of creating a new one. In the particular example of a CSR using a public/private key pair, you can reuse your current key set and not generate a new one.

Comment: You did not notice the CODENAMEONE tag - this question is specific to that develpment environment.

Comment: Correct. I may decide to leave this answer nonetheless since it is a recurring problem in iOS development.